# Latex for telegram whatsapps and email

Tags: xetex, luatex, programming

In the site of [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) we can write mathematics formulas with latex codes. It converts automatically the codes to Math. formulas.

can one do  the same in "telegram", Whatsapp. or emails systems as yahoo or gmail? that is we write our latex codes but after that we send our message it would be convert to math formula.

Comment: MathJax IS NOT LaTeX. That being said, some applications do use LaTeX, but they usually output an image or a PDF

Comment: Some Jabber/XMPP clients have a plugin for this, one I used in the past which supported it was [Gajim](https://gajim.org/) ([latexplugin description](https://dev.gajim.org/gajim/gajim-plugins/-/wikis/LatexPlugin)).

Comment: The Element matrix client (matrix messaging protocol) has experimental support using KaTeX iirc.